# Weapon Plugin in Phaser 3 Framework

Tags: phaser-framework

Phaser 2 had a Weapon Plugin to create a Bullet Pool (`var weapon = this.add.weapon()`). Now I'm switching to Phaser 3 and I cant find any examples or tutorials to create this. Maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A port of the weapon plugin is in progress and can be found [here](https://github.com/16patsle/phaser3-weapon-plugin).
The plugin is not fully complete yet as it doesn't have the frame cycle or bullet debug, but it should be mostly working. Credit for the plugin goes to 16patsle from the Phaser discord.

If you want to see an example of using bullets check out this [phaser example.](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cpools%5Cbullets.js)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this later :)